# AVPlayer pausing when app become inactive. How to automatically restart when active

Tags: ios, background, avplayer, playback

An AvPlayer will pause when the app goes in the background, and stays paused when the app goes back to the foreground. Is there an easy way to make the video play again (if it was playing when the background event happened) without having to do it manually for each AVPlayer ?

I see how I can have notification observers that will play my AVPlayers and that I will have to remove when the player gets deinit, but that's annoying.

Comment: is the video working on real device?

Comment: I don't really see what you mean but yeah we're testing on real devices

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift iOS -AVPlayer Video Freezes / Pauses When App Comes Back from Background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48473144/swift-ios-avplayer-video-freezes-pauses-when-app-comes-back-from-background)